# Creating an Password encrypted archive in ansible

Tags: ansible

How would I create an Password encrypted archive in ansible? The `archive` module does not seem to have this option.

Or is the only option to do this via the `command` module?

Comment: Maybe, [Vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html) feature can halp you

Comment: Vault isn't really designed for encrypting things within a playbook

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The archive module does not include a parameter to encrypt or password protect a file. Rather than use the archive module to compress the file, you can use the "shell" module (assuming you're connecting to a Linux-based machine) and simply build the encryption into your shell command.

I'm not sure what type of encryption you want, or what type of compression you're using, but for example, if you're using "zip" you can do basic password authentication like so;

```
shell: zip --password PASSPHRASE your-archive.zip your-files.txt
```

Of course that isn't your only option for encryption but it is a very basic example. Use the shell module over the command module if you need to make use of your users environment variables. Otherwise, they're very similar module.